# Get Input from html form in Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, alpha-vantage

I want to use the alpha vantage api to access financial data of a company via the stock id of a company. I'm trying to get the financial data of a company that the user inputs via the id of the company.
In the html file which is called home.html

```
<form method="post">
<label for="company_id">Enter Company ID (e.g., stock symbol):</label>
<input type="text" name="stock_id" id="sys" placeholder="e.g., AAPL">
<button type="submit">Get Stock Data</button>
```

The python file which handles calling the api and displaying the data is called views.py

```
@views.route('/home', methods = [ 'GET' ,'POST'])
def get_stock_data():
    symbol = request.form.get('stock_id')
    api_key = 'hidden'   
    interval = '60min'  
    outputsize = 'compact'  # You can use 'compact' or 'full' for the amount of data
    url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol={symbol}&interval={interval}&outputsize={outputsize}&apikey={api_key}'
    # Make the HTTP GET request
    response = requests.get(url)
    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    data = response.json()
    time_series = data['Time Series ({})'.format(interval)]

        # Create a Pandas DataFrame from the time series data
    df = pd.DataFrame(time_series).T  # Transpose to have timestamps as index

        # Display the Pandas DataFrame
    print(df)

    df['4. close'] = pd.to_numeric(df['4. close'])
    return render_template("home.html",  symbol=symbol, stock_data=df)
```

Comment: What problem are you having? The main problem I can see is that your route doesn't distinguish opening the page the first time and submitting the form.

Comment: Either use different routes for the page and the form, or use different methods.

Comment: @Barmar the error I get is that when I open the home page I get a 404 error saying it can't reach the api properly. So I put the form in a seperate route? For example I would keep one function 
'
def input():
   the input of stock id here?
'
def get_stock_data():
      the api calls here
'

Comment: What URL gives you a 404?

Comment: When you first open the home page, you send a `GET` request with no parameters. So you'll set `symbol` to `None` and it will get that error when it calls the API because the stock symbol doesn't exist.

Comment: Where is the code that displays the form when you initially open the page?

Comment: @Barmar this is the code 

<form method="post">
<label for="company_id">Enter Company ID (e.g., stock symbol):</label>
<input type="text" name="stock_id" id="sys" placeholder="e.g., AAPL">
<button type="submit">Get Stock Data</button>

but the form never loads as when the page initially opens I get the error 404 the link can't be found

Comment: @roganjosh The url that sends and retrieves data from the api
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol={symbol}&interval={interval}&outputsize={outputsize}&apikey={api_key}
This one

Comment: Since you don't have an `action` attribute in the form, it will try to submit the form to `/home.html`, not the `/home` route.

Comment: @Barmar so how do I make it get submitted to the /home route? I had an action attribute that sent it to the /home route but I still got the error.

Comment: `action="/home"` seems like it should work. If it doesn't, I think you have a problem with your Flask setup.

Comment: what should I do to change it then? My flask setup is the same one I copied from the documentation. I'll try making another project from scratch and copy paste the code to see if that resolves it maybe